# Including properties of child with belongsTo relation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I got a model that I am trying to extract the author from, comment

An activities model has comments, and each comment has an author

when I use include: ['coordinator', 'comments', 'likes', 'attendants'] I get the comments but I do not get the author they are linked to

I tried include: ['coordinator', {'comments':'Author'}, 'likes', 'attendants']

but no luck

I also tried include: ['coordinator', {'comments':'userId'}, 'likes', 'attendants']

same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have setup `Activity belongsTo User` relationship for your models. That way `Activity.prototype.author` will be created.

   Setting `Author hasMany Activity` is not enough, as it will create `Author.prototype.activities` only.

   ```
   // in models.json
   Activity: {
     options: {
       relations: {
         author: {
           type: 'belongsTo',
           model: 'User',
           foreignKey: 'userId'
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. The following query should work for you:

   ```
   // value for `filter` parameter
   { include: {
       coordinator: true,
       comments: 'author',
       likes: true, 
       attendants: true } }
   ```

Comment: Activities has an array of comments. Comments is its own model... Activities hasMany Comments. Each comment has a author. I am trying to access the author of the activity. The author of the activity is called the coordinator. I need the author of each comment.

Comment: Could you create a simple app reproducing your model structure? Also post the code you are using for querying the server.